# How to automatically scroll down a div when new content has been added (From xmlhttp.open)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/kv5gbamg/ - I made a jsfiddle showing kind of what the system does

Basically, I want to know how I can make the scrollbar go to the bottom every time a new message has been recieved.

Every 100MS my system updates the div with any new messages that will have been sent.

But sadly it doesn't automatically scroll to the bottom of the page when a new message has been received!

My system is simply checking a php file every x seconds

Here is a snippet of my code that does this:

```
echo "<div class='msg'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "";
    echo "<div class='username'>" . $row['username'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div class='message'>" . $row['message'] . "</div>";
    echo "";
    }
echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

This is how it works:

- It gets the messages from the database and displays them in a div tag
- Users can also send a message to the database which makes a POST request

What I want it to do but cannot figure out:

- When the web page loads it should automatically scroll to the bottom
- Every time a new message has been received (So basically every time something is added to the database) it should then scroll down to the bottom of the page
- Even if a user is high up the page it should scroll them back down

**I have seen loads of these on StackOverflow but they only update once a BUTTON has been pressed, this, therefore, means that if someone was to send a message to me then I wouldn't have the page scrolled down as I wouldn't press the button**

I cannot see the question anywhere on StackOverflow that has been answered

p.s. Basically, the scroll system I want to have is just like the one on [Messenger (Desktop Version)](http://www.messenger.com/) but I cannot figure out how to get it to scroll

Thank you so much for taking your time to help me, I hope I have provided you with enough information to help me out! (Thank's so much, you don't know how much it means to help me out here)

EDIT:
**Here is my JavaScript function that is used to get the messages (In the database) from the PHP file**

```
function showmessage(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {

            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/backend-display.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

//Show any messages that will pop-up
setInterval('showmessage()',100);
```

Comment: This is not the code that does this. PHP is server side code, you need client side code, JavaScript. Please post your code that actually updates the document.

Comment: I know how PHP works friend, I was just showing that the javascript calls a php file that outputs a name and message from the database. I will add my Javascript in also, thank you very much!

Comment: Why not [https://jsfiddle.net/kv5gbamg/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/kv5gbamg/1/)?

Comment: @Spectarion This is because users would not be able to see any of their prevous messages!

Comment: Check that fiddle sir... I updated it.

Comment: @Spectarion Thank you so much for taking your time to make this, but it still seems to do the same thing on my end!

Comment: Give me the link of the JSFiddle you are seeing right now.

Comment: @Spectarion https://jsfiddle.net/kv5gbamg/1/

Comment: @Spectarion Users still can't see their messages with the link you sent me as it keeps scrolling to the bottom (You get the idea of what I want though, so thank you very much) Sir

Comment: How is the same? `$('#chatbox').scrollTop($('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight);` scrolls down the bottom of the chat div every time there is a new message. It can't be the same. And one more thing, sending the XHR 10 times per seconds is a **bad idea**. Consider checking [Web socket](http://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/). By the way: it's a little bit tricky to see that it's scrolling to the bottom because of the same messages so I added the timestamp so you could see it better: [https://jsfiddle.net/kv5gbamg/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/kv5gbamg/3/).

Comment: @Spectarion I changed the delay and yeah... Your code looks to work, I will implement it and let you know!

Comment: @Spectarion Could you explain to me how it works... And what's it's doing to know when there is a new message? (How does it know when a new message appears?)

Comment: Basically, whenever the server returns the data you will append that message to the div and then you will just scroll that div to the end of it since it's vertical scrollbar size will change with the every new message. So, logically speaking, whenever there is a new message, scroll to the bottom.

Comment: @Spectarion **It didn't work sir** I used this fiddle as an example of the system getting messages from the database.

You are just updating the scroll everytime the message is given

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @Spectarion https://pastebin.com/NqVszxZn

Comment: @Spectarion I want my code to execute everytime it recieves a new message from the XMLHttpRequest (Not when it's outputting 50 times as that was just an example of what happens in the actual system) Sir.

Comment: @Spectarion I am still very grateful for you trying though! :)

Answer (score 1):

** see example on full screen

```js
var i = 1;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  execute();
}, 1000);

$(document).ready(function() {
  execute();
});

function execute() {
  $("#chatbox").append("This would be a message recieved from a database using an xmlhttp request!<br/><br/>");
  getMessages();

  if (i == 50) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  i++;
}

function getMessages(letter) {
    var div = $("#chatbox");
    div.scrollTop(div.prop('scrollHeight'));
}
```

```css
#chatbox {
  padding: 5rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  height:300px; 
  width:75%; 
  margin:0 auto;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div id="chatbox">
</div>
</div>
Users could send a message if they wanted to (As there is a send box)
```

If you search this just add my getMessages() function..

Let me know if it's helpful for you.

Hope to help.

Comment: I put your code in a fiddle and nothing is happening?
https://jsfiddle.net/9ra8c2bs/

(I can't spell your name sorry for not adding it in) :(

Comment: It's empty for me (I am running Google Chrome)

Comment: u saved my life

Comment: I can't scroll up now hahah

Answer (score 0):

I think thats what you want
I added

```
$('#chatbox').scrollTop($('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight);
```

after append so we get the div height then scroll
here a new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qz50bmbm/)

Comment: I put your code in, but it simply scrolls to the bottom every second (Not when a new message appears)

Comment: @AcrylicTrain no ! the code is the same, after append it scrolls maybe because the text is the same look here https://jsfiddle.net/qz50bmbm/1/ and if the counter reach 50 it stops

Comment: @AcrylicTrain also you can try that with animate https://jsfiddle.net/qz50bmbm/2/

Comment: Your code does not work because I only want it to scroll down when a new message is recieved using a XMLHttpRequest. @Spectarion has the right idea.

Comment: Thats the code you provided in the fiddle, you can place same code where you went (eg: the function where it append the message)

Comment: Could you show me, I have provided my code in my post, how would I implement your code into my httprequest function?

Comment: try that :             if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = this.responseText;
$('#chatbox').scrollTop($('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight);                
            }